# show there f(x) with FTC integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a function f such that?

$$\int_{0}^x f(t) dt=x+1   $$

I used the FTC but i don't now where the +1 coming from ?

Comment: Think about what happens when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you answered your own question.

Suppose that such a function did exist. Then applying the FTC gives $$f(x) = 1$$ but then $$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = x\neq x+1$$ so you have reached a contradiction, and no such function exists.

Comment: It's OK, but doesn't the FTC give $f(x)=1$ *almost everywhere*?